# Fluent Nhibernate configuration method wont compile - expression does not produce value

Tags: vb.net, lambda, fluent-nhibernate

Code below will not compile. Line with **New SchemaExport(cfg).Create(True, True)** - expression does not produce a value.
I'm new to Nhibernate. Am I missing something? This is a conversion of a code from C# which complies fine.

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports FluentNHibernate.Cfg
Imports FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db
Imports NHibernate
Imports NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl
Imports Ninject.Activation
Imports Ninject.Modules
Imports OSIM.Core
Imports Configuration = NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration

Public Class IntegrationTestsModule  
    Inherits NinjectModule

    Public Overrides Sub Load()
        Bind(Of IItemTypeRepository).To(Of ItemTypeRepository)()
        Bind(Of ISessionFactory).ToProvider(New ntegrationTestSessionFactoryProvider)
    End Sub
End Class


Class IntegrationTestSessionFactoryProvider
    Inherits Provider(Of ISessionFactory)

    Protected Overrides Function CreateInstance(context As IContext) As ISessionFactory

        Dim sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure().
            Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(Function(c) c.Is(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("localDb"))).ShowSql()). _
            Mappings(Function(m) m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf(Of ItemTypeMap)().ExportTo("C:\Temp")). _
            ExposeConfiguration(Function(cfg) New SchemaExport(cfg).Create(True, True)).BuildSessionFactory()
        Return sessionFactory
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: What does the ExposeConfiguration method expect as an argument?  Perhaps you just need to change Function to Sub

Comment: Same code in C# `.ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(true, true))`

Answer (score 1):

The `ExposeConfiguration` method is defined as follows (vb):

```
Public Function ExposeConfiguration(config As Action(Of Configuration)) As FluentConfiguration
```

It takes an instance of `Action(Of Configuration)`.  You must change `Function` to `Sub` like this:

```
ExposeConfiguration(Sub(cfg) New SchemaExport(cfg).Create(True, True)).BuildSessionFactory()
```

Comment: Tried that. It doesnt compile either. There is a _syntax error_ under _New_

Comment: changed it to something like that `Sub(cfg) Dim SchemaExport As New SchemaExport(cfg) SchemaExport.Create(True, True) End Sub` Seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Came here with same question, but inline code above not working -- possibly because of NHIbernate updates.

Error was: "Expression does not produce a value".
I reckon NHibernate modified the SchemaExport tool in the meantime?

Anyways, here's a working code with NHibernate 5.2.0.0

For those new to lambda functions, please note the newlines

```
Dim fluentConfig = Fluently.Configure() _
        .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.UsingFile("hibernatetest.db")) _
        .Mappings(Function(m) m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())) _
       .ExposeConfiguration(Sub(cfg)
                          Dim se = New SchemaExport(cfg)
                          se.Execute(True, True, False)
                          End Sub) _
       .BuildSessionFactory()
```

Hope it helps.